Gowers' dichotomy for quotients
Gowers' dichotomy establishes that every infinite dimensional Banach space contains a closed infinite dimensional subspace that has an unconditional basis or it is hereditarily indecomposable.
A Banach space is hereditarily indecomposable if it does not contain a pair of closed infinite dimensional subspaces $M$ and $N$ such that $M\cap N= \{ 0\}$ and $M+N$ is closed.
Question: Which should be the statement of a version of Gowers' dichotomy for quotients?
I think that one of the alternatives should be that the space has a quotient $X$ containing no pair of closed infinite codimensional subspaces $M$ and $N$ such that $M+N=X$. However, I feel that having a quotient with an unconditional basis is not the other alternative. Having an unconditional basis looks like a "subspace related" notion.

For reflexive spaces, consider the dual form of Gowers' theorem to see what a quotient version should look like. Suppose $X$ is reflexive. Then $X$ is decomposable iff $X*$ is decomposable. Thus $X$ is HI iff every quotient of $X^$ is decomposable. Similarly, $X$ has an unconditional basis iff $X^$ has an unconditional basis. Thus  $X$ is unconditionally saturated iff every quotient of $X^*$ has a quotient with an unconditional basis.

(continued) For the unconditional case, a result that Bentuo Zheng and I proved is perhaps relevant: A reflexive Banach space $X$ embeds into a  reflexive space with unconditional basis iff $X$ is a quotient of a reflexive space with unconditional basis. The first condition is equivalent to $X$ embedding into any space with unconditional basis, while the second is  is equivalent to $X$ is a quotient of some $Y$ with unconditional basis and s.t. $\ell_1$ does not embed into $Y$.
